# Vectorisation in SciPy Cython special functions

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, cython

When working in Python, I need to evaluate Gauss hypergeometric functions on arrays of some given length. In order to speed up the prior operations on these arrays, I have moved to Cython and from scipy.special.hyp2f1 to scipy.special.cython_special.hyp2f1. However, whenever I try to run Python-type code on arrays, I recieve the following error:

```
Invalid use of fused types, type cannot be specialized
```

Here is a trivial snippet that shows the problem:

```
import cython
cimport scipy.special.cython_special as scipy_special
cdef double complex[:] test_function(double[:] a, 
                   double[:] b, 
                   double[:] c, 
                   double complex[:] z):
    return scipy_special.hyp2f1(a,b,c,z)
```

whereas if I ran the *equivalent* code in Python there would be no error. I believe it's because `scipy.special.cython_special.hyp2f1` only operates on scalars. Given this, I consider the following simple code:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as cnp
import cython
cimport scipy.special.cython_special as scipy_special

cdef double complex[:] test_function(double[:] a, 
                   double[:] b, 
                   double[:] c, 
                   double complex[:] z):
    cdef int i = 1
    cdef double complex[:] test_hyp = np.zeros(len(z)) + 1j*np.zeros(len(z))
    for i in range(len(z)):
        test_hyp[i] = cys.hyp2f1(a[i], b[i], c[i], z[i])
    return test_hyp
```

The problem is now that the following workaround actually takes **longer** than if I'd just used vanilla Python, so is there a quicker way?

I've tried a while loop type implementation, tried a NumPy vectorize on hyp2f1, tried setting a variable for len(z) to save evaluating it multiple times all with minimal results.

All help is very much appreciated

Comment: You can probably speed up the Cython code a little - use `cython -a` to annotate the bits that are slow. There's a few compiler directives like `boundcheck` that might help. However, the Scipy vectorized version is likely to be a very similar C-level for loop, so I doubt if you'll actually be able to beat it by much.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. I've tried disabling boundchecking with the decorator, and running `cython -a`. Apparently the slow part is the `cdef double complex[:] test_hyp = np.zeros(len(z)) + 1j*np.zeros(len(z))` line. Not quite sure how to get around this...

Comment: So `cython -a` shows you where it interacts with Python. That line probably isn't actually slow because it only runs once. However, you could simplify it with `np.zeros(len(z), dtype=np.complex128)` to avoid creating two arrays, multiplying by `1j` and adding.

Comment: @DavidW that's much neater thanks. It's given a few hundred ms speedup too!

Comment: Note that you can certainly run the loop in parallel here if the execution time is bigger than few ms for the whole loop.

Comment: With running the loop in parallel, and the suggestions that @DavidW suggested, the Cython code now runs in approximately the same time as the vanilla SciPy code (Cython about 10ms faster average over 20 runs on arrays of 10^6 elements for a,b,c,z in hyp2f1). That's good enough for me!

Comment: If you're overwriting all elements of the array anyway, there's no reason to initialize to zero; `np.empty` should be a bit faster than `np.zeros`.